# Chained hash table: interface and duplicates?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

ok so im implementing my own chained hashtable because the sdk im using doesnt have one. this is a theory question so code and language does not matter. the questions is:

if i do a GET element/object for a key, and the chained hashtable has 2 objects for this key, which do i return? an array?
so the GET function returns an array?
what if there is only 1 element? the Get function also returns an array?
im trying to make it as transparent as possible to the user.

does any1 have any info on what the function prototypes look like for a linked hash-table?

Comment: Instead of tagging all the biggest tags for attention, why not tag [data-structures]?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your application.  Typically, you wouldn't allow there to be multiple different entries in a hash table with the same key (you'd replace existing key/value pairs with the new key/value pair if you inserted an entry with the same key).

If you do support multiple values associated with the same key, it's totally fine to return all of them using whatever works best for you.  You could conceivably return an array, which might contain multiple values or might just contain one value.  Another option would be to return a pair of iterators that span the range of value pairs with the same key (the approach taken by the C++ `std::unordered_multimap`).

As for function prototypes: that depends on the language.  Typically, they look like this (in Java-ish notation):

```
boolean add(KeyType key, ValueType value);
boolean containsKey(KeyType key);
boolean remove(KeyType key);
int size();
ValueType get(KeyType key);
Iterator keyIterator();
Iterator valueIterator();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you've been down-voted but it's not a bad question.

I suggest doing some googling and research online so that your understanding of the data structure is more complete.

I suggest this article: http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Chaining

You can see there in the first example they're using basic linked-list chaining, although open addressing is another option.

In terms of your return value I would be consistent and always return a list if you're adopting the chaining method (rather than a single value if only one exists) that way calling code can always expect to receive a list and then iterate over the content - if it's one or more results then you can deal with it easily. If however you return a list for multiple, or a single value then your method isn't what I would consider consistent (unless you document it as such).

Hope that helps!